# Why is a simple sed command not working on the raw csv file I downloaded from an EXO instrument?

Tags: bash, sed, output, csv

I have hundreds of csv files downloaded from an EXO instrument that I want to reformat. The first part of every file contains general information on the instruments followed by a table with header and measurements.

My goal is to delete everything in these files up to my header, which starts with "Date". This has been working seamlessly on practice files using the command:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '/Date/,$!d' test.csv > newfile.csv
```

The problem is that when I try to run this command on my raw csv data files the output file is empty. If I copy and paste this raw data file into a new sheet and save it as a csv file it works. I am able to use the sed command replacing digits and deleting specific lines using line numbers in my raw data files, so I know that sed is generally accessing these raw csv files. Does anyone have any idea where the root of my issue might lie? Thank you, and please let me know if clarification is needed.

Example of file:

```
sep=,
Unit ID:,
User ID:,
Site:,hrA
Log Interval:,60.00

Model, Submodel, S/N, S/W Ver
Handheld,2, 18C102285,1.0.33
4P Sonde,1, 17F104914,1.0.73
CT,1, 17F101355,3.0.5
ODO,1, 15J101782,3.0.0
pH/ORP,1, 18F103460,3.0.0
Turbidity,1, 15H104135,3.0.0
Depth,3, 17E101397,3.0.0

Date,Time,°C,mmHg,DO %,DO mg/L,DO %L,SPC-uS/cm,TDS mg/L,SAL-ppt,pH,ORP mV,NTU,Chl RFU,Chl ug/L,DEP m,Lat,Lon
07/22/2019,08:20:22,24.861,757.7,98.0,8.12,98.7,5.6,3.629,0.00,7.15,276.5,6.20,,,0.000, 41.93080,-70.06403,
```

Example of the file:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the test.csv file that is not working. At least one line before the one containing 'Date' and one line after that line.

Comment: From where do you get that csv file? From a Linux, MacOS, or Windows operating system? There might be different line feed syntax, that causes confusion.

Comment: I am working with Ubuntu on a Windows operating system. When I copy paste the file into a new file and rename it, it does work. I will paste an example of what the file looks like into the question.

Comment: Take an od on the raw file and see how the line endings are set up.  A CR left at the beginning of the line might mess things up.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thanks for your quick reply! Looking at notepad I don't see any issues in the file. The sed command works using digits, it's just not working with text.

Comment: @sudodus That doesn't work either, I haven't been able to change any text (whether replace or delete) in the raw files, only digits. It seems so strange that the commands work when I copy paste the exact file content into a new file too, I feel like the issue must be in the raw file.

Comment: I suspect that the problem is the {carriage-return + line-feed} for line feed in Windows, where Linux uses line-feed only. You can try to convert the csv file with `dos2unix` and try again.

Comment: Something ugly may invisibly hidden in that files. By copying you remove the invisible stuff. I suggest to do a `hexdump -C` of the file and paste the last piece including the `Date` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your input file and I have no problem, using end of line both for win and for linux.

Please try to use grep:

```
<test.csv grep -P '^(Date|[0-9]+/)' > newfile.csv
```

It's not exactly what you ask, but I hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your command works on the test files I created, but unfortunately not on my raw input files, they are still creating empty new files.

Comment: @SophiaFeuer I can help you, only if I have something similar to your raw input. Could you share something more similar to the raw data?